# Determine if ColdFusion function is native or user defined

Tags: coldfusion

I'm writing a utility that will parse CF code and identify functions that need to be mocked when writing tests.  In order to make the "should be mocked" list not include native CF functions I need to be able to identify them.

I'd rather not maintain a list of native functions to check against.  The only solution I've come up with so far is to use `getMetaData` and include only things found by that method.  This is very little code and will certainly work, but I'm wondering if there's a simpler method with lower overhead for making the determination.

Example:

```
<cffunction name="foo">
  <cfset LTrim("  spaces!") />
  <cfset myFunction(42) />
</cffunction>
```

Here I'd parse and see `LTrim` and `myFunction` and want to know, for each one, if it's a native CF or a UDF in the same component.

Comment: If a function is defined in a CFC that you wrote, it's not a native CF function. There's no way to overwrite native CF functionality with a function of the same name as you can with plain Java. Or am I misunderstanding the intent? Are you looking to find any function calls within your code or just defined functions?

Comment: Yes, looking to identify all function calls within my code and programmatically determine is it one I wrote or is it a native function.  I'm hoping for something like `isNativeCFFunction(<function name string>)` that I can pass each item in a list to (`"LTrim,myFunction"` in the above example) and get back a bool for each one so I can work with the filtered list of non-native functions programmatically.

Comment: `getMetaData` is probably your best bet, but keep in mind that if the component extends another cfc, only the methods declared in the cfc will be in `getMetaData(obj).functions`. You'll have to recurse up `getMetaData(obj).extends` until you hit the base component class to find any parent functions.

Comment: Ah - good to know.  That info will probably save me an hour and a headache. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [getFunctionList()](http://cfdocs.org/getfunctionlist) it returns a struct where each key is the name of a builtin function supported by the engine. This has been there since CF4.5 and works on Railo/Lucee as well.

Comment: If whatever is parsed isn't listed in the getFunctionList(), you may want to use isCustomFunction() to determine if it's truly a custom function and not something else. https://cfdocs.org/iscustomfunction